# Updating 'Date' Data based on Current Date

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table and it consists a column of `next_update` (which is in a date format), `time_left` (which is in the unit of days). How could I program it for example the `next_update` is 27/02/14 and the `time_left` is 3 days for today(24/02/14) view in a php webpage but for tomorrow view in the php page will be automatically deducted to 2 days. I'm using postgresql as my database and php as the web interface. The main problem now is how can I make the value of `time_left` be minus by the `next_update` with the current date.

I've gone through some basic manual but still have no idea to set this up. Sincerely thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
<?php
$now = time();
$next_update = strtotime("2014-02-27");
$datedifferent = $next_update - $now;
$days = floor($datedifferent/(60*60*24));
if($days > 0) {
echo $days.' more days you have';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT next_update, next_update - now() as time_left FROM <your_table>
```

You may also want to apply function `EXTRACT` to subtract necessary time units from interval ([documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT))